# Scraping website only provides a partial or random data into CSV

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping

I am trying to extract a list of golf courses name and addresses from the Garmin Website using the script below.

```
import csv
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


courses_list= []
for i in range(893): #893
  url = "http://sites.garmin.com/clsearch/courses?browse=1&country=US&lang=en&per_page={}".format(i*20)
  r = requests.get(url)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

  g_data2=soup.find_all("div",{"class":"result"})

for item in g_data2:
  try:
      name= item.contents[3].find_all("div",{"class":"name"})[0].text
      print name
  except:
      name=''
  try:
      address= item.contents[3].find_all("div",{"class":"location"})[0].text
  except:
      address=''

  course=[name,address]
  courses_list.append(course)

with open ('PGA_Garmin2.csv','a') as file:
        writer=csv.writer(file)
        for row in courses_list:
                writer.writerow([s.encode("utf-8") for s in row])
```

After running the script, I end up not getting the full data that I need and further when executed it produces random values and not a complete set of data. I need to extract information from 893 pages and get a list of at least 18000 but after running this script I only get 122. How do I fix this script to get the complete data set and produce the needed CSV with the complete data set of golf courses from the Garmin Website. I corrected the page page numbers to reflect the page set up in the Garmin website where the page starts at 20 so on.

Answer (score 0):

Just taking a guess here, but try checking your `r.status` and confirm that it's `200`? Maybe it is possible that you're not accessing the whole website?

Stab in the dark.

Comment: How do I go about checking that. I think it is not accessing the whole site and only producing some data. Can you provide a script that can check?

Comment: @Gonzalo68 you don't need a script. 

`if r.status == 200: print 'okay'`